# Page Break issues in fpdf and php

Tags: php, fpdf

I have to generate multiple pages in fpdf by php.on first section i am using multicell.that works fine.after that i am using cell in a loop.

```
 $GetMultiCellHeight = $pdf->y - $y;
    $y = $y + $GetMultiCellHeight;
    $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);



 $pdf->Cell(30, 10, 'FILE NO', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(80, 10, 'FILE NAME', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(30, 10, 'DATE', 1, 0, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(50, 10, 'TYPE', 1, 0, 'C');
    $y = $y + 10;
    $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);

while ($rowSubmission_files = oci_fetch_row($parse_Submission_files)) {

 $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $rowSubmission_files [1], 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(80, 10, $rowSubmission_files [2], 1, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $rowSubmission_files [5], 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf->Cell(50, 10, $rowSubmission_files [6], 1, 0, 'L');
        $y = $y + 10;
        $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
}
```

I have two rows in my database to print file details.
after generation of pdf i am getting each rows in a new page. how to solve this?thanks in advance.

Comment: check you values to make sure they fit the cell -> `If automatic page breaking is enabled and the cell goes beyond the limit, a page break is done before outputting`->http://fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm

Comment: yes ,all the values are fit the cell

Comment: but here the y value is setting on each new page